# Troubleshooting Windows 10 re-install

Tags: windows, boot, partitioning

I accidentally initiated a hard drive wipe on a Windows 10 partition and stopped the process as soon as I noticed (less than a second), but it was too late.

- This is a dual boot PC with separate Windows and Linux partitions, and I can still switch to my Ubuntu startup partition without issue.

When attempting to boot Windows, this is the sequence of what happens, along with my troubleshooting steps:

1. "Preparing Automatic Repair" begins
2. "Choose an option" screen is shown
3. I first try "Continue", but nothing happens.
4. I then choose: Troubleshoot > Reset this PC and keep my files

   - Result: Cycles back to home "Choose an option" screen
5. Troubleshoot > Advanced Options > Startup Repair

   - Result: "Couldn't repair your PC", which lists the path to a log file, and a "Command Prompt" option *(I wonder if this might be useful for troubleshooting?)*
6. Boot to a Windows InstallUSB > Install Now > Upgrade option is chosen

   - I then get the following "Compatibility report screen", which is where I am stuck [image: Screenshot]

What are the next troubleshooting steps given the above?

Is it possible there is more I have to do before reinstalling Windows?

Comment: What do you mean by _"initiated hard drive wipe"_?  That you selected to format the Windows OS partition?  If so, and the quick format process started, the OS partition will not contain any files/directories _(view in `notepad` > `CTRL`+`O`, or from Linux)_.  If that's the case, use `TestDisk` to recover the partition table.  If the partition was not formatted and still has files/partitions, issue the following command sequence: `bootrec /fixmbr` > BIOS only: `bootrec /fixboot` > `bootrec /rebuildbcd` - if it finds an install, add it, if not, reboot once the command completes.

Comment: _Cont'd..._ Download: [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).  Also, Windows can only be upgraded when the InstallUSB's / ISO's `setup.exe` is executed while booted to Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. As to how I 'initiated a hard drive wipe' it was via the 'Anti-theft' feature of Bitdefender.
Accidentally chose wrong device.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix the MBR in the system by using Command Prompt and issuing:

```bat
BootRec /FixMbr && BootRec /FixBoot && BootRec /ScanOs && BootRec /RebuildBcd
```

Comment: `bootrec /scanos` is not needed, as `/rebuildbcd` does that, and `/fixboot` only works on BIOS motherboards, not UEFI _(UEFI requires extra steps, mounting and entering the EFI boot partition, in order to use `/fixboot`)_